# plane curves with two points of high multiplicity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an irreducible plane curve in $\mathbb{P}^2_\mathbb{C}$ of degree $d$. Let $D$ be a quartic with three irreducible components with normal crossing singularities, i.e. a conic and two lines in general position.

**Question**  *Does there exists a $\mathcal{C}$ with $d>1$ intersecting $D$ in only two points $P_1, P_2$ such that there exists only one tangent line for $\mathcal{C}$ at each point?*

By simple consideration such two points should be nodes of $D$ and singular points of $\mathcal{C}$.

I have an argument to answer the question but I was wondering if there exist general methods for dealing with these problems.